# Custom js functions not being called in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, truffle

I am using webpack 3.8.1.
In my app.js I have a number of functions that I want to call on startup and when I click a button, however none of these get called.

e.g.

in my app.js :

```
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click',console.log("Help"),false);
if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
}

function init(){
  console.log("INIT")
}
```

in the html:

```
<input id="button" type="button" value="Create/Retrieve" class="btn btn-primary">
```

It is almost as if all of app.js get wrapped up so deep it is not accessible.
I have tried many ways to somehow activate an event when I click the button, but to no avail.

Is there some way that I can make function call on startup and another function when I click a button. It sounds so stupid but I have been fighting with this for a while and need help.

Thanks

Phill

Comment: Did you put your `<script type="javascript" src="app.js" />` somewhere other than the end of the `<body>` tag?

Comment: yes, and I can see it in dev tools under sources.

Comment: Sorry. I meant, make sure that the <script> tag appears at the end of the body. Otherwise, the DOM objects you're setting properties on won't exist at the time you set them.

Comment: Still the case. I removed everything and started again but I have not nailed down what it was that caused the problem. Will post something here when I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not sending a function to addEventListener.

Try `.addEventListener('click',()=>{console.log("Help")},false);`